# How make the default like show with numbers instead of only a like icon of Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have tried this:

```
<div style="width:52px;overflow:hidden;">
 <fb:like layout="button_count"></fb:like>

 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true,
      xfbml: true});
      };
      (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.type = 'text/javascript';
      e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      e.async = true;
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());
 </script>
</div>
```

Where it only shows a like button of FaceBook but does not shows how many people liked it. After pressing like it only shows a V sign of facebook (that i liked it).

How do i show always total liked numbers?

Comment: You could use the standard like plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: xbonez: i did that. But still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using XFBML Version for Like Button.

Make Sure you have define XML namespace to yout html as follows.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Define your following code just after body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true,
      xfbml: true});
      };
      (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.type = 'text/javascript';
      e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      e.async = true;
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());
 </script>
```

then Use your button code on page like

```
<div style="width:52px;overflow:hidden;">
<fb:like href="http://www.google.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div style="width:52px;overflow:hidden;"></div>` - this is used to hide the numbers. Therefore i did not had numbers but all the rest. After removing that i have now numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Read this link

[developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

Update

You must have to choose this option in Like plugin (*see image*)
[image]

Comment: YES - i have done that. But still i have no numbers like you have shown too. I have only like after like it shows a V sign thats it.